# Transitive closure R={(a,b),(b,a),(b,c),(c,d),(c,e)}

Tags: relations

> Choose the transitive closure of the relation R={(a,b),(b,a),(b,c),(c,d),(c,e)}

My answer was

```
(a,c),(b,d),(a,d),(b,e),(a,e)
```

But it was wrong. The correct answer was:

```
R={(a,a),(a,b),(a,c),(a,d),(a,e),(b,a),(b,b),(b,c),(b,d),(b,e),(c,d),(c,e)}
```

I do not understand why pairs such as `(a,a)` is needed in a transitive closure, isn't that a reflexive closure? I also do not get why the same pairs was added, like `(a,b)` when it was already in the relation before the closure (perhaps this is just to show the full relation after the closure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ is in your relation that is $(a,b)$ gives us that $a$ is related to $b$ and $(b,a)$ gives us that $b$ is related to $a$. So for transitivity $a$ should be related to $a$ that is $(a,a)$ should be there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The closure og R always contains R. You need to iteratively add pairs to R by taking two existing ones with the form `(r,s)` and `(s,t)` and then add `(r,t)` if it isn't there already. I.e. since you have `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` you must add `(a,a)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)